# Entering formula into range using dim variables

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if you could help me in building a particular macro. I would like to build a user interface as part of an existing macro which helps people build a VLOOKUP formula (as they’re not particularly familiar with Excel).

- I am able to set the Lookup_Value by using ‘FirstSedol’ below
- I am then able to return the range by a user interface box as ‘Trades’.
- I am then able to return the number of columns within the range ‘Trades’ as ‘ColumnCount’ as I want the VLOOKUP to search in the first column of the range ‘Trades’ and return the final column and hence used ‘ColumnCount’.

I know all parts work individually as I’ve returned their outcome using message boxes etc. However, I just can’t get the code to input a VLOOKUP formula into Cell H3 on my worksheet below (in bold). Would you be able to offer any assistance by any chance?

```
Dim Trades As Range 'Prompts user to select range of cells for the VLOOKUP
    Set Trades = Application.InputBox("Select the range of cells from the first sedol on the asset allocation (top left), through to bottom right hand corner of the 'changes' column ", "Select cell range", Type:=8)

Dim ColumnCount
    ColumnCount = Trades.Columns.Count

Dim FirstSedol As Range 'Asks the user to select the first SEDOL code to lookup
    Set FirstSedol = Application.InputBox("Select the first sedol to search for", "Select first sedol", Type:=8)

**Worksheets("Quick Value").Range("H3").Formula = "=Vlookup(FirstSedol, Trades, ColumnCount, FALSE)*-1)"**
```

Many thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the variable from the string and concatenate the address for the ranges.

```
Worksheets("Quick Value").Range("H3").Formula = "=Vlookup(" & FirstSedol.Address(0,0) & ", " & Trades.Address(0,0) & ", " & ColumnCount & ", FALSE)*-1"
```

Comment: This half addresses the problem, however, it applies the following formula;
"=VLOOKUP(E3, C16:M71, 11, FALSE)*-1".
Unfortunately, E3 is in the active sheet but the range C16:M71 is selected by Dim Trades on a seperate sheet. It seems to lose the reference to the other named sheet as part of this formula.